# React DnD - conflict with native drop events

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am using React DnD in a SPA I am currently working on and it's built as a plugin for wordpress! Wordpress native media uploader uses HTML5 onDrop event to add files into the media library and since I am using React DnD , I am no longer able to drop files into wordpress media uploader! I am aware of the fact that this bug has already been reported in git issues and has been asked in stackoverflow -  [How to avoid native onDrop event from being overwritten for react-dnd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747346/how-to-avoid-native-ondrop-event-from-being-overwritten-for-react-dnd), but sadly there is no response yet, both in git issues and stackoverflow!

I have been working with react dnd for a couple of months now, there is no denying that it's the best drag and drop library for react but issues like this makes it hard to use it in a large, diverse projects! After spending quiet a lot of time learning react DnD, I don't want to move away from it over such a small issue! Hope you guys can help me out!